# Local broadcast manager for downloading files

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-broadcast

I'm creating a local broadcast receiver for notifying an activity when a download has started and finished. I have two classes, one is the DownloadFileFromURL class that i call to download certain file, and in it I've defined this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("completeDownloadItem");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("completedItem", suraName);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

that in my opinion should send a broadcast to my DownloadManager class that has this code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.download_manager);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(itemReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("addDownloadItem"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                completeReceiever, new IntentFilter("completeDownloadItem"));

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver itemReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            Songs s = (Songs) intent.getSerializableExtra("newItems");
            Log.d("receiver", "Got song: " + s.getTitle());
        }
    };
    private BroadcastReceiver completeReceiever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("completedItem");
            Log.d("receiver", "Downloaded: " + message);
        }
    };
```

Can any one tell me what am I missing, should I define local broadcast receiver in the manifest or something?

here is the DownloadFileFromURL class:

```
public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String reciterName, suraName;
    private String file_url, filePath;
    private MediaScannerConnection msc;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private int songNumber;

    public DownloadFileFromURL(Context context, String reciterName,
            String suraName, String fileURL, int songNumber) {
        this.context = context;
        this.songNumber = songNumber;
        this.reciterName = reciterName;
        this.suraName = suraName;
        this.file_url = fileURL;
        db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    protected void createDialog() {
        // switch (id) {
        // case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        // dialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.downloading) + " "
        // + songName);
        /*
         * dialog.setIndeterminate(false); dialog.setMax(100);
         */
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        // default:
        // return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // createDialog();
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(file_url);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream
            File appDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getPath() + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name));
            appDir.mkdirs();
            File albumDir = new File(appDir.getPath().toString() + "/"
                    + reciterName);
            albumDir.mkdirs();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(appDir + "/"
                    + reciterName + "/" + suraName + ".mp3");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        // dialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        msc = new MediaScannerConnection(context,
                new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        msc.disconnect();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        msc.scanFile(filePath, null);
                    }
                });
        if (!msc.isConnected()) {
        }
        // dialog.dismiss();
        db.openDB();
        db.addDownloaded(songNumber, reciterName);
        db.closeDB();
        Intent intent = new Intent("completeDownloadItem");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("completedItem", suraName);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sucessfully downloaded " + suraName,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, local broadcast receivers don't need to be configured in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I have to say that I am as well a bit puzzled why the notification does not work; have you debugged into the code and checked if the broadcast is actually send out and whether the receiver is registered properly?

If you cannot get it working (for whatever reason), consider using a library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for your inter-component communication needs. Personally I haven't used the `LocalBroadcastManager` in ages...